# VB.NET send form post data like in browser with text and file

Tags: vb.net, post, httpwebrequest

I'm making one program in VB.NET, and I need to post to url adress(which i can't modify) with one text input and one file input(not image).

It really has to be post like in html `<form method="post">`, not that `php://input`. I need simple, but best working solution, great would be if it was without webbrowser, it's supposed to run on background and I wan't it to be as unassuming as possible.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can probably start by first understanding how the browser posts the content to the server using a tool like Fiddler (www.fiddlertool.com) and then emulate the same HTTP request using HttpWebRequest (or other HTTP classes).

Comment: It gets me `Content-Disposition: form-data` with names plus in that one with file also `Content-Type: application/ocet-stream`, but I still have no clue how to do that, I found many answers and questions, but all were for another language in the end, or were sending `php://input`.